# Matrix columns combination algorithm

Tags: r

I have try to do all combination by matrix columns by R as below
Firstly, I have a 4*3 matrix as below

```
> a
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    0    1    1
[2,]    1    0    0    0
[3,]    1    1    1    1
```

then we want to list total 3*1*2*2 = 12 combination, such as example below
one of example is

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    0    1    1
[2,]    0    0    0    0
[3,]    0    1    0    0
```

and the second example is

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    0    1    0
[2,]    0    0    0    0
[3,]    0    1    0    1
```

one column with only one number.
Currently, I already list down each column type, such as

```
> whole.combination
[[1]]
     b b b
[1,] 1 0 0
[2,] 0 1 0
[3,] 0 0 1

[[2]]
     b
[1,] 0
[2,] 0
[3,] 1

[[3]]
     b b
[1,] 1 0
[2,] 0 0
[3,] 0 1

[[4]]
     b b
[1,] 1 0
[2,] 0 0
[3,] 0 1
```

however, although i can using cbind by manual to generate one

```
> cbind(a[[1]][,1],a[[2]][,1],a[[3]][,1],a[[4]][,1])
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    0    1    1
[2,]    0    0    0    0
[3,]    0    1    0    0
```

**how can i combine each column by each matrix to generate one 4*3 matrix?**
but, does it have any efficient way to list all combination in once?
therefore, if i extend this problem by n*m matrix, i need one algorithm to generate those matrix combination.
thanks

Comment: type modify - we want to list total **312*2 = 12** combination 
we want to list total **3*1*2*2 = 12** combination

Comment: The question is unclear. Assuming the input is matrix `a`, where in the other matrices is column 1? And how do you get the product `3*1*2*2`? I can understand `4+3*2*1`, 4 choices for the 1st column, 3 for the 2nd column, 2 for the 3rd column and only one choice left for the last column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I see what you are trying to do. First you are generating 3 x 4 matrices (rows*columns) not 4 x 3 matrices. Second you refer to an example matrix as `a` and the list as `whole.combination` but then your code refers to this list as `a`. I'll call the list `b`. First make the data reproducible with `dput()`:

```
b <- list(structure(c(1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1), dim = c(3L, 3L)), 
     structure(c(0, 0, 1), dim = c(3L, 1L)), structure(c(1, 0, 
     0, 0, 0, 1), dim = 3:2), structure(c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), dim = 3:2))
```

Your goal is to make all 3*4 matrix combinations by taking 1 column from each of the 4 parts of list `b`. First we need the combinations:

```
cmbs <- expand.grid(1:3, 1, 1:2, 1:2)
```

Now compute `result` which is a list containing 12 3*4 matrices representing combinations of the columns from the four matrices in list `b`:

```
result <- lapply(1:12, function(i) cbind(b[[1]][, cmbs[i, 1]], b[[2]][, cmbs[i, 2]],
          b[[3]][, cmbs[i, 3]], b[[4]][, cmbs[i, 4]]))
result
# [[1]]
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    1    0    1    1
# [2,]    0    0    0    0
# [3,]    0    1    0    0
#         . . . . .
# [[12]]
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    0    0    0    0
# [2,]    0    0    0    0
# [3,]    1    1    1    1
```

As your comment suggests, it would be better to have a more general approach to the problem. Here is another approach that does not require knowing the size of `b` or the number of columns in each part:

```
# Get the number of columns in each part of the list
cols <- lapply(b, \(x) seq(ncol(x)))
# Get the combinations
cmbs <- expand.grid(cols)
# Build the matrices for each combination
results <- lapply(1:12, \(i) mapply(\(x, y) {x[, y]}, b, cmbs[i, ]))
results
```

This produces the same result as the original answer.

Comment: Hi dcarlson, thanks for your response. it great helpful and solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your great suggestion, I can apply this method for all m*n matrix.
It is really super workable.

```r
cols <- lapply(b, \(x) seq(ncol(x)))
cmbs <- expand.grid(cols)
n <- dim(cmbs)[1]
results <- lapply(1:n, \(i) mapply(\(x, y) {x[, y]}, b, cmbs[i, ]))
```

Now, I have to do more study about `lapply` function.